# Carousel - How to loop through elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, carousel

I'm trying to figure out how to loop through each list element one at a time and apply a function to them when they run, I've tried several methods and some hints would help!

HTML structure

```
<div class="custom-item">
  <ul>
    <li id="first-slide" class="slide active"><h1>Test</h1></li>
    <li id="second-slide" class="slide"><h1>Test</h1></li>
    <li id="third-slide" class="slide"><h1>Test</h1></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I've worked out an `each` function that if i understand correctly will handle the changing of classes, this is where I'm failing to loop through each element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( ".slide" ).each(function( i ) {
    if ( this.className !== "active" ) {
      this.addClass("active");
    } else {
      this.removeClass("active");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You're on the right track, you'll figure it out. (Best delete this)

Comment: Yeah, you're likely to get a lot of duplicate question flags. There are tons of options out there. You've said other options "are not executable for me without rewriting a lot of code". Well what are you expecting in the way of answers here? Likely any code we provide will require you to rewrite a bit of yours. Maybe re-ask your question to be more "answerable".

Comment: @Jonathan Thanks, no chance of getting a clearer hint by any chance?

Comment: @philtune At this stage I'm trying to figure out how to loop through each list element one at a time and apply a function to them when they run, ill reflect that in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use $(this).hasClass to check for "active" class.

**JSFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/39o0bagv/

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $( ".slide" ).each(function( i ) {
                if ( $(this).hasClass("active") ) {
                    $(this).removeClass('active');
                    $(this).addClass("changed");
                } else {
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                }
            });
        });
```

**CSS**

```
.active {
    color: red;
}
.changed {
    color: blue;
}
```

The loop will check if the element has 'active' class and replace it with 'changed'. And vise versa.

Answer (score 1):

I've added a css class so that you can see the active class being toggled. Your methods for checking, adding, and removing the class weren't write, so it was failing with a script error. See what I've done below, using the classList property. However, judging from your post title, I'm not sure if maybe you're wanting to pause on each one and then continue. In that case the javascript setInterval method might be the tool you want. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
            $(".custom-item").find('.slide').each(function(){
                if (!this.classList.contains("active")) {
                    this.classList.add("active");
                } else {
                    this.classList.remove("active");
                }
            });
        });
```

```css
.active{
  background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div class="custom-item">
         <ul>
            <li id="first-slide" class="slide active"><h1>Test</h1></li>
            <li id="second-slide" class="slide"><h1>Test</h1></li>
            <li id="third-slide" class="slide"><h1>Test</h1></li>
         </ul>
     </div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xgabuqzz/)

Answer (score 1):

Fix: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qu71zo38/)

```
  $(document).ready(function() {

            $('.slide').each(function(i) {
                if ( !$(this).hasClass("active")) {
                    $(this).addClass("active");
                } else {
                    $(this).removeClass("active");
                }
            });
        });
```